# What's the difference between dispatch and next in Redux middleware?

Tags: redux

#### What's the difference between `dispatch` and `next` in *Redux* middleware?

```js
export default function sampleMiddleware(store) {
  return next => action => {
   store.dispatch(action)
   next(action)
  }
}
```

Comment: fairly good documentation here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html is there something specific that confuses you?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Dispatch initiates new action and it's go through full chain of middlewares.

Next – send current action into next middleware in chain.

Comment: what does it mean to go through "full" chain of middlewares? so that is the final resulting action from something like #applyMiddleware whereas #next will return the current point at which an action is being changed?

Comment: @mangocaptain, the way I understand it, inside a middleware, `next` moves on the the next middleware while `store.dispatch` places given action at the start of the middleware pipeline. If so, you can create an infinite loop with `store.dispatch`, but you can't with `next`.

Answer (score 17):

```
createStore(reducer,
 applyMiddleware(
 middlewareA,
 middlewareB,
 middlewareC
 )
);
```

> Calling next(action) within middlewareB will cause the action to be
>   passed to middlewareC and then the reducer. Calling dispatch(action)
>   within middlewareB will cause the action to be passed to middlewareA,
>   then middlewareB, then middlewareC, and finally to the reducer,
>   returning the execution back to middlewareB. Calling dispatch()
>   multiple times is a common and valid practice. next() can also be
>   called more than once, but this is not recommended as any action
>   passed to next() will skip the middleware before the current one (for
>   example, potentially skipping the logging middleware).

Comment: Perfectly explained!