# React Redux middleware's #store.dispatch(action) vs #next(action)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux

I'm learning about react redux middleware from the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) and want to know what he means by "the action will actually travel the whole middleware chain again?" Does that mean the `store.dispatch(action)` will have the final `dispatch` that is returned at the end of the middleware, whereas `next(action)` will only point to the `dispatch` at a certain point of the middleware function?

> It does a bit of trickery to make sure that if you call
>   store.dispatch(action) from your middleware instead of next(action),
>   the action will actually travel the whole middleware chain again,
>   including the current middleware. This is useful for asynchronous
>   middleware, as we have seen previously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dispatch and next in Redux middleware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160457/whats-the-difference-between-dispatch-and-next-in-redux-middleware)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/ca73kt2v/

Answer (score 2):

In redux [`middleware`](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) is a function that patches `dispatch` function to extend functionality. And `next` function inside `middleware` is in fact just a copy of `store.dispatch` function.

```
function patchStoreToAddLogging(store) {
  let next = store.dispatch
  store.dispatch = function dispatchAndLog(action) {
    console.log('dispatching', action)
    let result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    return result
  }
}
```

So when you `return next(action)` you return a result of `dispatch` function, with all previous `middlewares` in the chain applied, to the next middleware.

But when you call `store.dispatch` function you call a final `dispatch` method return from middleware chain with **all** `middlewares` applied.

Comment: next is not patched dispatch, it is new dispatch which calls previous dispatch [docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)