# Dispatch method in middleware not triggering reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-thunk

Using the store method `dispatch` from the parameter provided by Redux Thunk middleware does not trigger the reducer. While using `next()` works properly as it triggers the reducer. Why is this happening?

***middlerware***

```
export default function createSlimAsyncMiddleware({
    dispatch,
    getState
}) {
    return next => action => {
    const {
        types,
        callAPI,
        shouldCallAPI = () => true,
    } = action;
    if (!actionIsValid(action)) next(action);
    if (shouldCallAPI(getState())) {
        return Promise.resolve(getState());
    }
    const [pendingType, successType, errorType] = types;
    dispatch({
        type: pendingType
    });
    return callAPI()
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({  // Does not work, use next()
                type: successType,
                payload: response,
            });
            console.log('call resolved with type', successType)
            return Promise.resolve(getState());
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({  // Does not work, use next()
                type: errorType,
                payload: error,
            });
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    };
}
```

***store***

```
const store = createStore(
    appReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(
    thunk,
    createSlimAsyncMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history)
    ))
)
```

Regarding this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160623/4428183 the `dispatch` should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stated in the linked response you included, but calling `dispatch()` will create a new action, which then goes through the entire middleware chain from the beginning. In your case, this includes the middleware you're troubleshooting. From what I can see, the only time you call `next()` is in the case that an incoming action is deemed invalid. Otherwise, the subsequent API call results in `dispatch()` being called again whether the call succeeds or fails, and so the action never gets to the reducer because it's constantly being set at the beginning of your middleware chain and never gets to move along via `next()`.

When you say this code doesn't work, what is the specific behavior? Does your app hang? Does it crash? Because this scenario essentially sets up a recursive function with no base case, I'd bet that you're seeing 'maximum call stack exceeded' sorts of errors.

I guess I'd ask why you need to use `dispatch()` for request results as opposed to sending them along using `next()`, or why you haven't set this up in a way that sets a conditional that uses the result of the previous call to determine whether the API gets called again.